# Docker containers on WSL2 don't get added to the bridge network

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Issue**: My containers (all of which are webservers) can't communicate with each other by container name (the DNS lookup fails). I can make them communicate by creating a new network and adding each created container to that network, but I'd prefer to not have to do this manually.

**Details**: According to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) all new containers should automatically get added to the `bridge` network and be able to communicate to each other simply by `container_name:port`. However, on WSL2, even though the `bridge` network exists, the containers don't seem to be added to it because they can't communicate with each other by name.

**Workarounds that I've tried**:

- I am making it work right now by creating a network and adding containers on that network. However, this is cumbersome and not feasible when I eventually have a large number of containers.
- `docker-compose` is an idea, but my integration test suite creates containers from inside it and all my integration tests will not work (and I'll have to switch to a new integration test suite entirely).

Is there a way that I can make new containers automatically join the bridge network (or my own network) **without using `docker-compose`**?

- Docker Desktop version: 3.2.2 (61853)
- Windows 10; Build 19042.928

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my docker containers WERE getting added to the default bridge network. However, them not being able to communicate with each other [is an intended design.](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) Containers on the default `bridge` network can't talk to each other by host name; they must use IP to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker run --network="bridge" <mycontainer>
```

You can check exactly what is going on inside with

```
docker inspect <containerID>
```

Comment: I tried this out and it does work, except I had to specify my own network instead of `bridge`. Maybe there's something wrong with the default `bridge` network?

Comment: Okay, I've confirmed that the containers ARE getting added to the bridge network by default - but on the bridge network, they are unable to communicate with each other. I'll investigate this further to see what the issue is.

Comment: I saw your answer further down (can't comment on it though, not enough rep) and that explains why I had this issue inside my QNAP docker instance until I used docker-compose to add the containers to the qnap custom lxbr0 bridge (with the syntax I posted above, and/or via docker-compose depending on the app).  I thought it was something specific to QNAP's setup, but it seems this is vanilla docker behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with these test options to isolate issue

1- check bridge network itself working fine in WSL system, as WSL is new have some issue.
2- checking container through  if yes it means docker is creating container correctly
3- try to resolve IP to check if it is resolving, if yes then it can be purely DNS issue
4- as per 3rd point will check DNS pod if it is functioning correctly.

If possible could you share exact error  and DNS pod status.